# Change value of v-model and update v-text-field

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I made a fiddle where I tried to change one value of an array via code while it's used as `v-model` of a `v-text-field` from Vuetify.

The problem is, when I write something in the text field it does change the value correctly immediately, so I made a button that sets the value of the array in that specific index, it doesn't seem to be working, so I made another button to print it and it does work.

The first button changes the value to 0 as I'd like but in the `v-text-field` it still has the last typed value.

How to change the value of the `v-text-field` when the "reset" button is pressed?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      model: [1, 2]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    restart() {
      this.model[0] = 0
    },
    showInConsole() {
      console.log("Current value:", this.model[0])
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="app">
    <v-layout row wrap>
      <v-flex xs4>
        <div class="headline">Change value of model[0]</div>
        <div class="headline text-xs-center">{{model[0]}}</div>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs8>
        <v-text-field solo v-model="model[0]"></v-text-field>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs12>
        <v-btn @click="restart ()">Reset to 0</v-btn>
        <v-btn @click="showInConsole ()">Show in console current value</v-btn>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[Link to my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/H3lltronik/05vbg2ja/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [Vue reactivity problem](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats).

Basically, Vue cannot detect the changes to an array when you directly set an item with the index

You should use `Vue.$set`

```
restart () {
  this.$set(this.model, 0, 0)
}
```